# Kubenetes gcloud container engine get-credential error

Tags: google-app-engine, kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I am trying to connect Google Container Engine from my local machine using `gcloud` sdk but i am getting below error.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>gcloud container clusters get-credential
s cluster-2  --zone us-central1-a --project myapp-00000
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
ERROR: (gcloud.container.clusters.get-credentials) environment variable HOME or
KUBECONFIG must be set to store credentials for kubectl
```

I have check at HOME location there is not .kube folder created and not environment variable set by default, so i have created  `KUBECONFIG` environment by myself after that i am getting  below error :-

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (OSError): [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Tool\\config'
```

i have started `gcloud` sdk as admin and it have all the correct Permission.

**EDIT**

I am using below version (which are latest as of today)

```
Google Cloud SDK 129.0.0
kubectl
kubectl-windows-x86_64 1.4.0
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK>kubectl version
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"4", GitVersion:"v1.4.0",
```

Comment: I saw that you filed the following Github [1] as well and a solution to your question has been provided. If it worked for you, is it possible to post it as an answer and accept it, so other people can benefit from it. [1]: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/34395

Answer (score 1):

I take it you set `KUBECONFIG` env to 'C:\Tool\config'? That error is gcloud failing to write due to missing admin privileges; I don't know if you need to run the shell as admin. You might also try the `HOME` directory. Note that gcloud will attempt to create any missing directories on the path to the kubeconfig file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue.
It turns out that KUBECONFIG refers to a file and not to a directory.

So if you set up KUBECONFIG to 'C:\Tool\config\kubectl.cfg' it should work fine.